# HilbertMaze task on Codility

Tags: algorithm, hilbert-curve

Can anybody give me a hint about how to approach following task from Codility: https://codility.com/programmers/task/hilbert_maze/

I would be able to find the shortest path by generating the maze and searching for the shortest path using BFS, but since the worst-case time complexity is expected to be O(N) I don't think this would be the right way to go. Time complexity of BFS is O(|V| + |E]) where V is number of vertices and E the number of edges. For example if N = 3, we have a grid of size 17x17 and it's intuitively obvious that we can't find the path in only 3 steps.

So, either the indicated time complexity is wrong and should be something like M^2 or there is a quick trick to simply calculate the distance between two points without using graph algorithms. I found some algorithms for calculating Hilbert distance for 2 given points (if that's what is needed here), which use bit manipulations etc. but couldn't understand them at all. Moreover, I think that the goal of the task is to find out on your own how to calculate the distance and not using an existing formula.

Is there somebody who solved this task and can help me further? Thanks!

Comment: Hilbert distance is just substracting 2 hilbert indices. How can it help or the distance (without the walls) help to find shortest distance?

Comment: @AnthonyHuang published [his answer](https://codility.com/demo/results/training78EPWE-7M3/) (100% score). It's over 500 lines of C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

1. Every points location can be defined by an array of quadrants and their orientation (it will have N elements) - each element representing the orientation in the previous quadrant. The whole maze having upwards orientations
2. You need to define this array for both points. For example: if N = 2 and the point is in the lower left quadrant then it will have the orientation to the left. We take this quadrant and we rotate our coordinate system so it will the same orientation. This way we define the next quadrant and orientation pair in our new system. So if we have our point in the lower left quadrant then it will have orientation to the left, but as this was relative to our previous orientation (which was also to the left) this will become an upwards orientation.
3. At this point we have all the quadrants and orientation down to the smallest maze that contains our point. From backwards (from the smallest maze) we need to solve them. Every maze can be solved by the following rules:

- if our point in our current quadrant is on any of the extremes (meaning that any of the coordinate's components are either the lowest or highest of the quadrant) we leave it where it was, otherwise check next points
- if our point is downwards or at the middle of the current quadrant then we move to the quadrants lowest middle point (these goes relative the previously defined orientation, i.e.: if our orientation is upwards then we will move our point at the topmost middle point)
- if our point is upwards (in the relative direction) we will have to move it to the topmost middle point

4. Storing these moves, we check if we have any common elements in the two array belonging to the two points:

- if not we calculate the distance between the two endpoints and the we add up all the distances from the two moves list (in this list every distance can be calculated as coordinate component subtractions, i.e.: abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2))
- if we have common elements then we delete every move after that including the common elements and we calculate the distance as mentioned at the point before

This solutions can be optimised, it is just meant to present and idea to start with.

**Edit:** Here is my implementation of the above presented solution in Swift3: https://codility.com/demo/results/training9WWFXU-EWC/

Comment: What do you mean by "each element representing the quadrant in the previous quadrant"?

Comment: @OldPro probably he wanted to say "each element representing the orientation in the previous quadrant"